# unable to establish connection on channel when i login from firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
 void signIn({
required String email,
required String password,
}) {
```

emit(LoginInitialState());
FirebaseAuth.instance
.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
.then((value) {

```
     emit(LoginSuccessState());
  }).catchError((error) {
    emit(LoginErrorState(error.toString()));
  });





dependencies:
bloc: ^8.1.2
cloud_firestore: ^4.8.3
firebase_auth: ^4.7.1
firebase_core: ^2.15.0
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
flutter_screenutil: ^5.6.0
```